# Are xibs considered out of date?

Tags: xib, uistoryboard, deprecated

Now that Apple has released storyboarding, are xibs deprecated? I've found some of my old tricks (i.e. connecting other views in ib) to not work anymore. But yet at the same time it's nice to have all my views in one file. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Deprecated?* Not yet.
- *Outdated?* Yes. Since iOS 5, many new Interface Builder features (like static table view cells and unwind segues) are *only for storyboards and not xibs*.
- *Apple also recommends using storyboards* in their own documentation:

  **[View Controller Programming Guide for iOS:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)**

  > In short, creating a user interface means instantiating and configuring many objects and establishing the relationships between them, which can be time consuming and error prone.
  >
  > Instead, use Interface Builder to create **storyboards**.

  **[Table View Programming Guide for iOS:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)**

  > The easiest and recommended way to create and manage a table view is to use a custom `UITableViewController` object in a storyboard.

Comment: A little late but still very helpful. Thanks!